# garchOxFit in R-oxo file does not match

Tags: r, garch, ox

Could someone please help me with trying to get the Ox interface to work in R. I get the following errors as output:

This version may be used for academic research and teaching only
Link error: 'packages/Garch42/garch' please recompile .oxo file to match this version of Ox
Hata oluştu: file(file, "r") : bağlantı açılamadı
Ek olarak: Uyarı mesajları:
1: 'C:\Ox\bin\oxl.exe C:\Ox\lib\GarchOxModelling.ox' komutunu çalıştırırken 1 durumu oluştu 
2: In file(file, "r") :
  dosya 'OxResiduals.csv' açılamadı: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

This error message indicates you are not using the correct Ox console release. Every oxo is compiled for a particular ox console version/release. So you need to install the Ox console wich fit with your oxo.